# page not found when I try to access URL in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot, jetty

I am trying to access the `localhost:8080/tree-model-app/ping` URL which should return `true`. But I get `404` for that URL.

Here is my `main` for `Spring Boot` application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TreeModelApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TreeModelApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() throws Exception {
        ServletRegistrationBean registrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(new RootServlet(), "/tree-model-app");
        registrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registrationBean.setAsyncSupported(true);
        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

This is my `servlet`

```
public class RootServlet extends ServletHttpHandlerAdapter {
    public RootServlet(HttpHandler httpHandler) {
        super(httpHandler);
    }

    public RootServlet() {
        this(WebHttpHandlerBuilder
                .webHandler(toHttpHandler(routingFunction()))
                .build()
        );
    }

    private static RouterFunction<?> routingFunction() {
        return route(GET("/ping"), new PingHandlerFunction());
    }

}
```

And this is my `handler`

```
public class PingHandlerFunction implements HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> {
    @Override
    public Mono<ServerResponse> handle(ServerRequest request) {
        return ok().body(fromObject("true"));
    }
}
```

This is my `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootVersion"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

group = 'com.lapots.tree.model.web'

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:$springBootVersion"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springBootVersion"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:$springBootVersion"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:$springBootVersion"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:$springBootVersion"
}
```

But when I try to access `localhost:8080/tree-model-app/ping` I get

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: have you tried removing the `port` number?

Comment: @andre3wap you mean from url? It does not work without it at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution I do like this. I don't know why the mapping `/tree-model-app` or `/tree-model-app/*` does not work during initialization in `ServletRegistrationBean` but I set it to `/*` here.

```
ServletRegistrationBean<Servlet> registrationBean = 
        new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new RootServlet(), "/*");
```

Next I set the path I want directly in router function

```
private static RouterFunction<?> routingFunction() {
    return route(GET("/tree-model-app/ping"), new PingHandlerFunction());
}
```

And it started to work `localhost:8080/tree-model-app/ping`